# Naming variables/fields?? Not accepting names - Thymeleaf and Spring Boot MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am new to Spring Boot and I am am working on creating connecting the front of an application to the back at the moment.

I used this site https://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/ 
to work on a simple example and it worked fine. It uses the names 'name' and 'age' for the two fields, and getAge, and getName etc for getters and setters.

**This code works:**

HTML form:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="#" th:action="@{/}" th:object="${personForm}" method="post">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Name:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" th:field="*{name}" /></td>
                    <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}" th:errors="*{name}">Name Error</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Age:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" th:field="*{age}" /></td>
                    <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('age')}" th:errors="*{age}">Age Error</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><button type="submit">Submit</button></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Person java class

```
public class PersonForm {

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=2, max=30)
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @Min(18)
    private Integer age;

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Person(Name: " + this.name + ", Age: " + this.age + ")";
    }
}
```

Controller

```
@Controller
public class WebController extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/results").setViewName("results");
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String showForm(PersonForm personForm) {
        return "form";
    }

    @PostMapping("/")
    public String checkPersonInfo(@Valid PersonForm personForm, BindingResult bindingResult) {

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "form";
        }

        return "redirect:/results";
    }
}
```

**I have simply changed the names of the variables to the below:** (2 strings instead of an int and a string). The following error is displayed when I try to view the page: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring4.processor.attr.SpringInputGeneralFieldAttrProcessor' (form:33)

Line 33 has " th:field="*{testcolumn}" " on it.

Is there certain naming conventions you must follow with thymeleaf perhaps? I cannot find information about it. Thanks

Person class:

```
 @NotNull
    @Size(min=2, max=30)
    private String testcolumn;

    @NotNull
    private String testcolumntwo;

    public String getTestcolumn() {
        return this.testcolumn;
    }

    public void setTestcolumn(String testcolumn) {
        this.testcolumn =   testcolumn;


    }

    public String getTestcolumntwo() {
        return testcolumntwo;
    }

    public void setTestcolumntwo(String testcolumntwo) {
        this.testcolumntwo = testcolumntwo;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Person(Name: " + this.testcolumntwo + ", Age: " + this.testcolumntwo + ")";
    }
```

HTML Form:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/}" th:object="${personForm}" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{testcolumn}" /></td>
            <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('testcolumn')}" th:errors="*{testcolumn}">Name Error</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Age:</td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{testcolumntwo}" /></td>
            <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('testcolumntwo')}" th:errors="*{testcolumntwo}">Age Error</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><button type="submit">Submit</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Could you post the entire stacktrace to see more details?

Comment: Surely not a naming conflict, don't think there is such strict naming convention in Thymeleaf. I was able to run your code without problems. A typo perhaps?

Comment: I found the problem - my code was slightly different to above in that there were underscores in my field names - it couldn't parse the names because of this - good to know for future reference when naming in thymeleaf.